# MassTransit Subscribe error: A receive endpoint with the key was not found

Tags: .net, masstransit

I'm migrating MassTransit dependency from version 5.1.2 to 5.2.0 and after doing that some tests stop working and the following exception has been thrown:

> A receive endpoint with the key was not found: API.Faturamento.Eventos.Testes.Integrados.Support/MessageA/Subscriptions/test_subscription_message_a

I'm using .Net Framework 4.6.2 and the test works perfectly with MassTransit 5.1.2 but it stops working when I change it to 5.2.0 version.
I've searched a lot for some solution, but I've not seen anyone who has passed through this issue before.

TestInitialize Method

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        queueName = ConsumerTest.ConsumerTestQueueName;
        _busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(true, true);
    }
```

The CreateUsingAzureServiceBus Method

```
    public static MassTransitServiceBus CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(this IBusFactorySelector busFactory, bool logPreEvent = false, bool logPostEvent = false)
    {
        string serviceBusUrl = "sb://your-service-bus-url.servicebus.windows.net/";
        string serviceBusAccessKey = "your-service-bus-access-key";
        IServiceBusHost host = null;
        IBusControl busControl = null;

        busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(new Uri(serviceBusUrl), host =>
            {
                host.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                host.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(tokenKeyName, serviceBusAccessKey);
            });
            cfg.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            cfg.MaxConcurrentCalls = 80;
            cfg.PrefetchCount = 100;
            cfg.UseRenewLock(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(280));
        });
        busControl.ConnectConsumeObserver(new MassTransitConsumeObserver(logPreEvent, logPostEvent));
        busControl.ConnectReceiveEndpointObserver(new MassTransitReceiveEndpointObserver(logPreEvent, logPostEvent));

        return new MassTransitServiceBus(host, busControl);
    }
```

TestMethod

```
    public void PublishMessage_ShouldReceiveAndHandle()
    {
        _busControl.Subscribe<FirstSubscribeConsumer, MessageA>("test_subscription_message_a");
        _busControl.Subscribe<SecondSubscribeConsumer, MessageA>("second_test_subscription_message_a");
        
        _busControl.Publish<MessageA>(new { Value = $"MessageA: {Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}" });
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

And the MassTransit extension method where the exception is thrown after that this first subscribe is called

```
    public static void Subscribe<TConsumer, TMessage>(this IServiceBusHost host, string subscriptionName) 
        where TMessage: class 
        where TConsumer : ContractConsumerBase<TMessage>, new()
    {
        host.ConnectSubscriptionEndpoint<TMessage>(
            subscriptionName,
            e => { e.Consumer<TConsumer>(); }
        );
    }
```

Comment: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2241)

Comment: The transport code was entirely rewritten in 5.2.0, take a lookt at: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/e9209bc14f0ba30037d6766a0e0933e535ff3151